# Expected failure during unittest tearDown

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a Python unit test which fails during teardown. This is an expected failure for now. I'm using the standard [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html) library in Python 2.7.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import unittest

class MCVE(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.invariant = True
    def tearDown(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.invariant)
    @unittest.expectedFailure
    def test1(self):
        self.invariant = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Because the failure happens during teardown, the `expectedFailure` decorator causes some confusion as to whether the test case succeeded: it's both reported as an unexpected success (because there's no failure in the test case itself) and as an unexpected failure (because the teardown fails).

```
uE
======================================================================
ERROR: test1 (__main__.MCVE)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 8, in tearDown
    self.assertTrue(self.invariant)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1, unexpected successes=1)
```

I don't want to move the invariant check out of the teardown because it needs to be performed for all tests. On the other hand, I want to make it as obvious as possible that this test case is expected to fail, without modifying the test case (which is fine as it is now). I'd rather not skip the test, because if it succeeds unexpectedly, that could indicate another bug. Ideally I'd like to keep the decorator mechanism, and tweak the decorator or the teardown code or both.

How can I annotate an explicit failure for a test case during teardown?

Comment: I think the test will still run, so `invariant` will still actually be changed to False. It's just that the failure will not be counted as a failure when you use the `expectedFailure` decorator.

Comment: I don't think unittest has a way of defining expected failures in teardown - your assertions should be within the test itself.

Comment: Couldn't you assert if `invariant` got correctly changed to `False` within `test1`? So, that if it gets unexpectedly changed the test would fail making it possible for you to notice the anomaly

Comment: Call `teardown` from within `test1`.